# When are objects copied rather than passed as a reference'

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

If objects are passed by reference, and functions are objects, then can someone explain this behaviour:

```
function extendCopy(p){
  var c = {}
  for (var i in p){
     c[i] = p[i];
  }
  c.uber = p;
  return c;
}
var shape = {
   name: "shape";
   toString: function (){ return name; }
}
var twoDee = extendCopy(shape);
twoDee.toString = function() { return "2d shape" }

>>>shape.toString
>>>function (){ return name; }
```

How come `twoDee.toString` is not just a reference to `shape.toString`? Surely the line `c[i] = p[i];` in the copy function would just set the property of the new object to a reference to the same property in the copied object?

**EDIT**

This can be simplified:

Why does this return `"test"` and not `"modified"` if functions are objects and objects are passed by reference? Is it because I'm actually replacing the "object" (function) entirely, with a new one on line 3?

```
a.toString = function(){ return "test" };
b.toString = a.toString;
a.toString = function(){ return "modified" };
b.toString();
>>> "test"
```

Comment: This example is wrong; `john` is echoed. Show the real code instead.

Comment: oh, you are right, let me adjust the question

Comment: You'll occasionally see false results in the console if it uses caching

Comment: Javascript always passes parameters by value (and for an object that value is a reference), but anyway that doesn't apply to the code that you have as you are not passing any parameters at all.

Comment: I tried to over-simplify the problem, I've posted the code that is confusing me

Comment: "If objects are passed by reference" "Objects" cannot be "passed" in JavaScript because "objects" are not values. The only values in JavaScript are primitives and pointers to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a property value that is a reference to an object only copies the reference. It doesn't cause the recipient of the value to be a reference to the other property.

Example:

```
var a = { x: { name: 'John' } };
var b = {};

b.x = a.x; // b.x points to the same object as a.x;

a.x = { name: 'Peter' }; // a.x points to a different object, b.x is unchanged
```

When you copy the value from `a.x` into `b.x`, the value of `b.x` is a reference to the same object that `a.x` pointed to, it's not a reference to `a.x` itself.

The same goes for function references. When you copy the reference of a function you only copy the reference value. If the original is replaced by a difference reference, it doesn't change the value that was copied from it.

Comment: Thanks, I found the question really hard to put into words (hence someone's downvote!) but you've elocuted your answer perfectly. This makes a lot of sense now!